# Mimekit - A suitable private key could not be found for decrypting

Tags: c#, encryption, x509certificate, x509certificate2, mimekit

I'm trying to decrypt and encrypt mime messages with the Mimekit Library, but when I try to import the certificate to the TemporarySecureMimeContext and then decrypt a message I encounter the following error:

> ```
> A suitable private key could not be found for decrypting.
> at MimeKit.Cryptography.BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext.<DecryptAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at MimeKit.Cryptography.ApplicationPkcs7Mime.<DecryptAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at Utils.MimeMailUtils.MimeMailUtils.<Decrypt>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Dev\Euroval\PasarelaAceuro\Utils\MimeUtils\MimeMailUtils.cs:line 105
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at PasarelaLibrary.Implementations.Caixa.GraphImplementation.LaCaixaGraphApiPasarela.<GetMessage>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\Dev\Euroval\PasarelaAceuro\PasarelaLibrary\Implementations\Caixa\GraphImplementation\LaCaixaGraphApiPasarela.cs:line 362
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at PasarelaLibrary.Implementations.Caixa.GraphImplementation.LaCaixaGraphApiPasarela.<Descarga>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Dev\Euroval\PasarelaAceuro\PasarelaLibrary\Implementations\Caixa\GraphImplementation\LaCaixaGraphApiPasarela.cs:line 167
> ```

and this is the code I'm using:

```
public static async Task<MimeEntity> Decrypt(MimeMessage message, X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    var encryptedContent = (ApplicationPkcs7Mime)message.Body;
    using var context = new TemporarySecureMimeContext();
    context.Import(certificate.AsBouncyCastleCertificate());
    return await encryptedContent.DecryptAsync(context);
}
```

Here is how I initialize the certificate:

```
public void SetSecrets()
{
    using KeyVaultClient client = VaultClientExtensions.GetKeyVaultClient(AzureVaultManagerSettings.ClientId, AzureVaultManagerSettings.ClientSecret);
    var secret = AsyncUtil.RunSync(() => client.GetSecret<string>(AzureVaultManagerSettings.SecretUrl));
    GraphApiSettings.PrivateCertificate = new X509Certificate2(
        Convert.FromBase64String(secret),
        string.Empty,
        X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
}
```

The problem with that is I already encrypted and decrypted messages using the WindowsSecureMimeContext, but the problem with that is my app service in which is deployed the application can't import the certificate due to lack of permissions and we cannot give it admin permissions.

--EDIT--

My Certificate already has a private key

[image: private key from certificate]

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the private key

Comment: I edited my question to add a Screenshot so I can show you the certificate already has a private key, so my question now is why the AsBouncyCastleCertificate extension method does not add the private key?

Comment: Ok, I investigated this and I know why the BouncyCastle.X509Certificate does not have the private key, but now how can I add the private key to the temporaryContext?